# How to convert seconds from date format and hour format

Tags: php, date

Now my output here:

```
$date = 25.10.17 02:35:57;
```

$seconds = ??????;

Because Now my php date output has standard date format.so how to i'm convert 
Seconds Format.please Answer me...

Comment: use strtotime function

Comment: are you doing this in mysql? If not why the tag?

Comment: You've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: I voted to delete this question; it's been asked already and too many times. You've probably done no research neither.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime() function of php to covert given time in seconds

```
   <?php
    $date = '25.10.17 02:35:57';
    echo strtotime($date);
    ?>
```

You can read more about function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php